# bash mail command to send attachment and also add message in email body

Tags: bash, email

On a utility Linux server, I have implemented a bash script to mail the output of a Perl script. The output is a .bin file, which goes as an attachment.

Now, in the same email, I also want to add some message and include the current time in message body. How can I mail the output of a script and also add message in the email body

Please note I don’t have write access to Perl script, so I can’t make any modifications there

Comment: The Perl script doesn’t store the output in a file, it throws the output on tty. Also, I want the output to be directly mailed to me instead of being stored in a file on the server.